# Scope error in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compile the given OpenCV - C++ source code using g++ compiler the compiling command being:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` vehicleDetection.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

I've also tried compiling the code by explicitly mentioning the libraries using

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o vehicleDetection vehicleDetection.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab
```

It returns the error:

```
vehicleDetection.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
vehicleDetection.cpp:96:2: error: ‘CascadeClassifier’ was not declared in this scope
  CascadeClassifier vehicleCascade;
  ^
vehicleDetection.cpp:101:7: error: ‘vehicleCascade’ was not declared in this scope
  if (!vehicleCascade.load (VEHICLE_CASCADE_NAME)) {
       ^
vehicleDetection.cpp:117:3: error: ‘vehicleCascade’ was not declared in this scope
   vehicleCascade.detectMultiScale (grayscaleSampleVideo, vehicles, 
   ^
vehicleDetection.cpp:118:22: error: ‘CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE’ was not declared in this scope
            1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, 
                      ^
vehicleDetection.cpp:121:3: error: ‘vehicleCount’ was not declared in this scope
   vehicleCount = 0;
   ^
vehicleDetection.cpp:124:42: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Point {aka cv::Point_<int>}’ requested
        vehicles[i].y + vehicles[i].height);
                                          ^
vehicleDetection.cpp:126:45: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Point {aka cv::Point_<int>}’ requested
    Point pt2 = (vehicles[i].x, vehicles[i].y);`
```

May someone enlighten me with the errors.
I beg pardon for disturbing with such trifle issues.
The source code is given herein-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define VEHICLE_CASCADE_NAME "path to cascade.xml"
#define SAMPLE_VIDEO_NAME "path to sample video"
#define WINDOW_NAME "Vehicle Detector"

int main () {

    int timeCount = 0;
    CascadeClassifier vehicleCascade;
    Mat captureSampleVideo, grayscaleSampleVideo;

    cout << "\nVehicle Detection" << endl << "NOTE: Press <Esc> to quit" << endl;

    if (!vehicleCascade.load (VEHICLE_CASCADE_NAME)) {
        cout << "ERROR: Classifier loading unsuccessful!!" << endl;
    }

    VideoCapture sampleVideo (SAMPLE_VIDEO_NAME);
    if (!sampleVideo.isOpened ()) {
        cout << "ERROR: Sample video loading unsuccessful!!" << endl;
    }

        while (1) {
        sampleVideo >> captureSampleVideo;

        cvtColor (captureSampleVideo, grayscaleSampleVideo, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist (grayscaleSampleVideo, grayscaleSampleVideo);

        vector<Rect> vehicles;
        vehicleCascade.detectMultiScale (grayscaleSampleVideo, vehicles, 
                                        1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, 
                                        Size(30, 30));

        vehicleCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
            Point pt1 = (vehicles[i].x + vehicles[i].width, 
                        vehicles[i].y + vehicles[i].height);

            Point pt2 = (vehicles[i].x, vehicles[i].y);

            rectangle (captureSampleVideo, pt1, pt2, 
                    CvScalar(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);

            vehicleCount += 1;
        }
        namedWindow (WINDOW_NAME, WINDOW_NORMAL);
        imshow (WINDOW_NAME, captureSampleVideo);

        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            destroyWindow (WINDOW_NAME);
            cout << timeCount << " ms" << endl;
            break;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is `CascadeClassifier` declared in some of the previously `#include`s files?

Comment: Hi @Ripi2 , Thanks for the advice. I added `#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp" ` and the scope error was resolved. That was quite silly from my part. About the third last error- `vehicleDetection.cpp:121:3: error: ‘vehicleCount’ was not declared in this scope
   vehicleCount = 0;` is resolved with `int vehicleCount = 0;`  and  the last two errors are resolved by removing the two '=' sign after `Point pt1` and `Point pt2` respectively.